# Index error when printing line from an external file and using functions

Tags: python, function, file, readlines

I've set a function to print from a file and set variables so that I can choose what line from the file. I set q1 = 0, do a function that prints line[q1]. Then I change the value of q1 and do the function again to print line[q1] but this time it being a different line. But I get "IndexError: List index out of range". It's not out of range because if I print line[5] it works but if I set q1 = 5 and print line[q1] it doesn't?
The function works the first time round but not the second.
This is coursework so i'm begging for help

```
def qs(): # ask questions
    global q1
    global a1
    global a2
    global a3
    global a4
    line = questions.readlines()
    if difficulty == "easy":
        print(line[q1])
        easyanswers = line[a1], line[a2]
        print(easyanswers)
    elif difficulty == "medium":
        print(line[q1])
        mediumanswers = line[a1], line[a2], line[a3]
        print(mediumanswers)
    elif difficulty == "hard":
        print(line[q1])
        hardanswers = line[a1], line[a2], line[a3], line[a4]
        print(hardanswers)
    else:
        print("Invalid difficulty selection")
        q()
    answer = input("Answer: ")

def qnumber(): # does next question
    global question
    global q1
    global a1
    global a2
    global a3
    global a4

    if question == 1:
        question = question + 1
        qs()
        qnumber()
    elif 1 < question < 6:
        question = question + 1
        q1 = q1 + 5

question = 1 # track of question number
q1 = 0 # question line number
a1 = 1 # answer 1 line number
a2 = 2 # answer 2 line number
a3 = 3 # answer 3 line number
a4 = 4 # answer 4 line number

qnumber()
```

Comment: fix indentation please!

Comment: @Synnipoe please learn first built_in functions and definitions before writing a script(like: `class, dict, lists,tuple etc...`). All applications must be in a sipiral cycle. Priority is the first one in the last row.

Comment: please can you explain to me where i'm misunderstanding? @dsgdfg

Comment: `if (question + 1) <= len(line) :` ignore unwanted condition.  `global blah_blah` is wrong, `def qs(tuple_of_external_variables)` is correct.